# Button call controller method, display results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, methods, controller, nested-resources

I have resources

```
User #from devise
Stream
Subscription
```

In my routes.rb file I have subscriptions as a nested resource to users.

```
resources :users do
  resources :subscriptions
end
```

In Stream#show view I have a button that should save the @stream.title to @subscription.title.

```
<%= button_to "Subscribe", subscriptions_path(@subscription), :class => "button", :method => :post , :remote=>true %>
```

In my Subscriptions Controller

```
def create
@stream = Stream.friendly.find(params[:stream_id])
@subscription = current_user.subscriptions.create(subscription_params)
@subscription.title = @stream.title
@subscription.save
respond_to do |format|
  if @subscription.save
    format.html { redirect_to @subscription, notice: 'Subscription was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @subscription }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @subscription.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
  end
```

Rake route

```
 POST   /users/:user_id/subscriptions(.:format)          subscriptions#create
```

And in my Stream#index view I want to display the @subscription.title ' s

```
  <tbody>
<% for subscription in @subscriptions %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= subscription.title %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

And in my Streams Controller

```
def index
@streams = Stream.search(params)
@subscriptions = current_user.subscriptions.build(subscription_params)

end
```

I have added a reference index for each subscription to a user

```
class AddIndexes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :subscriptions, :user, index: true
  end
end
```

I am recieving a NoMethodError in Streams#show, undefined method 'subscriptions_path'.
And a NameError in StreamsController#index, undefined local variable or method 'subscription_params'

Comment: Please add your full controller code of `StreamsController`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You get undefined method subscriptions_path because rails translates your `format.html { redirect_to @subscription, notice: 'Subscription was successfully created.' }` wrong. Change your `@subscription` into a proper helper `path` call. If you're not sure what you should provide here, you may want to run `rake routes > routes.txt` in the shell and find your `subscriptions` route definition there and call it with `_path`
2. You get undefined method `subscription_params` because most probably you haven't defined `subscription_params` anywhere. You most prolly want to access your subscription params like `params[:subscription]`. As for the proper key when it comes to accessing the `params` hash, it all depends how you build your form in a view.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= button_to "Subscribe", subscriptions_path(@subscription), :class => "button", :method => :post , :remote=>true %>
```

The resource above doesnt exists, you have only defined a nested resource subscriptions inside users.

So you should have something like this instead, using the nested resource **user_subscriptions_path**.

```
<%= button_to "Subscribe", user_subscriptions_path(@subscription), :class => "button", :method => :post , :remote=>true %>
```